# Creating Exception sub-class for handling business logic errors or using error codes?

Tags: java, exception

I am using Java and I would like to find out the pros and cons of creating Exception sub-class to throw biz exceptions or should I be using error codes to handle biz exception?

Let's take a typical banking application for example, there are several exception when a transfer of funds would go wrong. i.e Insufficient Fund, Invalid Target Account, Exceed the maximum transfer limit for the day.

Should I create a list of error codes to return to the caller? or should I be throwing `Exception` class (inherit from `Exception`) to the caller?

If I were to create `Exception` for every biz exception, there could possibly be a lot of `Exception` classes.

Comment: Might be worth a read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2286747/creating-exception-classes-for-lot-different-error-codes?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use Exception class all the way to throw your exceptions with specific message and even could send out error codes.

But you business logic should decide it whether you want to create an exception or go with error codes.

With custom exceptions comes a great advantage i.e. you could define hierarchy. For your example of banking application, we  know that if there comes **Insufficient Fund, Invalid Target Account, Exceed the maximum transfer limit for the day** situations, then all these are at first TransactionFailures due to some reason. Hence your exception hierarchy could be like below:

```
             TransactionFailureException
             /           \
           /              \
         /                  \
       /                     \
InsufficientFundException  /  InvalidTargetAccountException / MaxLimitReachedException
```

Hence exception handling provided you with a standard business logic level error hierarchy which is understood by everyone and hence is helpful is setting up standard.

But error code are also very important as these specify a specific problem just by code number.

Would recommend using both for best robust application.

Answer (score 1):

The big advantage of exception handling is that it keeps your code cleaner. The code looks like a sequenece if actions without too many if statements, so that the main use case is apparent from the source code.

In Java, the compiler also helps because it forces you to declare the types of exceptions that a function may throw.

Now, if you have many different reasons for failure, you don't necessarily need to create a separate exception class for each reason. They could share the same exception type, with an enum inside of it providing more specific information. Or you may create separate exception classes and have each of them inherit from the same base exception. If the logic of handling the exception is the same for all of them, you need to catch the base exception.

Answer (score 1):

**You can use both together for a robust error handling and logging purpose.**

1. Create a predefined list of error codes and respective error descriptions and let those store some persistence storage. Each time your application starts up, you load the same in a Map. Storing in persistence storage will have two benefits:

   **a. Scalability:** If you have a very large set of error codes, it is good to store those in table instead of hard coding those in code.

   **b. Maintainability:** Maintenance will be easy. No need to modify your code each time there are some changes in your error code or error description. Also adding any new error code is easy. For example, one single insert query is sufficient in your error code table for a new error code.
2. Create custom business exceptions based on the the business category (For example, one category could be **InvalidAccountInformation**, another category could be **InvalidTransaction** and so on). You can pass your custom error code in these custom business exceptions. You can fetch the custom error description with the error code and log accordingly. **A good idea would be your custom exceptions should be subclass of `RuntimeException` class.**

Comment: Why would you store error codes in a database?

Comment: @MrWiggles, If you have a really large set of error codes, it is always a good idea to store them in a database table and load them on application start up. If you have relatively small set of error codes, no need to store in persistence storage and store them in your code itself.

Comment: What difference does the size of them matter? I see zero benefit to storing these in a database at all but it *does* add complexity

Comment: I see you've updated the question saying you can add error codes directly to a database, but how would these be used without a code modification?

Comment: Yes, it matters. For cleanliness and maintenance reason, in my code I will prefer to do this. Particularly when I have thousands of error codes. it is much more cleaner approach. However, it all design choices, you are free to hard code the same in your code if you like to do so.

Comment: Lets say I am loading err id and desc while application starts up with a select query from errordesc table. Now any new error id added in my table will also gets added with this in my error map as part of existing load logic. Now I can use this new id in my new modules with out touching my existing module. This approach will really be helpful for multi module project. Would it have been code change in existing module, you had to compile the existing module as well just because of this simple change.

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd need to recompile existing code when adding an error code, also - *thousands* of error codes? That to me would signal something is very wrong, but YMMV

Answer (score 1):

Using error codes would lead to:

- call the function and return error codes
- then handle the error codes in an if-else-cascade
- and in each conditional block recover the context
- and then recover the function

In this case exceptions could help a lot:

- you will not have to return an error code, you can use the return value for more meaningful results
- you will not have to handle errors in an if-else-cascade but with a try-catch-cascade (which is better for the reader to see that somethin is recovered)
- you will not have to recover the context, because the exception could hold the necessary context information (if designed correctly)

If error codes are just a throw-aways that are ignored and not recovered one simple exception type holding an error code would be sufficient.